# Convert Html to plain text with razor

Tags: razor, html-encode

I have this rich text stored in the database

```
<p>   <em><strong>strong</strong> and <em>em tag</em> normal text <u>
```

It is stored as a string with its tags.

Now I want ti put this text in the title of `<a>` tag without displaying all the html code.

I've tried

```
<a name="modal" title="@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(MyVariable).ToString()"> link </a>
```

But it still displays all the tags.

Comment: Decoding does not mean stripping tags.

Comment: Is there a method which can remove tags and keep only the text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the tags using regex:

```
string plainText = Regex.Replace(MyVariable, "<.*?>", string.Empty);
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. I added "RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(plainText, "&nbsp;", " ");" to replace spaces

Answer (score 0):

In your file.cshtml You can try use html.WriteRaw() helper.
But in .net core must specify correct mvn class namespace.
I wrote own helper method in my cstml file. I used WriteLiteral() method to make all tags like "&#1234"; or "< br/>" to plain text. Writelitaeral write text directly into buffer so my method return empty string.

```
@functions {
public string RemoveFormat(string message)
{
    WriteLiteral(message);
    return "";
}
}
...
<p>
@RemoveFormat(@Model.data)
...
```